# How to Manage a Web Portal

Tags: php, html, web

Can someone give me ideas of how the admin managing the school announcements and events of a web portal? Like how they put it in there? is it manually coding? I just started programming php.

Comment: Are you asking the modules?

Comment: Can you be more specific?  It sounds like you're basically asking how to build a website in PHP.  Which is *far* too broad to be meaningfully answered here.

Comment: Example like the school web portal how the admin put the school and announcements and update it? Is it manually coding? because i don't know what to do, im doing the website layout. I don't know how to design it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use pure `HTML` manually write the code inside the portal . 
If instead use `PHP` is normally integrated with a database in such a way that once created the basic structure ( `PHP` that reads from `Database` ) the whole system is dynamic.

Normally if it comes to dynamic sites are used in the **CMS** that are web applications that interact with the database to enter data (a real data entry)

List of some free **CMS**:

1. [WordPress](https://www.wordpress.com/)
2. [Joomla](https://www.joomla.com/)
3. [concrete5](https://www.concrete5.org/)
4. [Drupal](https://www.drupal.com/)

---

If you are learning you should look at the official documentation for **PHP** [Manual link](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/)

And look **MySQL** which is a great open source database [MySQL link](https://www.mysql.com/)

Comment: Because every week the announcements and events are changing. So every maintenance what the admin doing to change the announcements? manual coding?

Comment: @TikboyPengan - No the admin use a **CMS** (Like WordPress or Joomla or Custom CMS) otherwise inserted by hand into the database announcement (the latter approach is not normally used by anyone)

Comment: so i need to learn that cms too? other than php,js? my thesis is student portal.

Comment: @TikboyPengan - If you want to create a "dynamic portal", where once you have created the basic code you do not need to place any additional code, but sometimes you just need to use a CMS to insert ads, events, pages, events (whatever you want) and you can also use people who do not know any programming language because it will be as a simple data entry program. So you can study what is and what can you do with CMS

Comment: Is joomla free? i see a trial word?

Comment: @TikboyPengan - Yes, you can look here for more info: https://www.joomla.org/about-joomla.html